# Wrapping Divs / StyleSheet problems

Tags: html, css

Is there anyway to make it so instead of using multiple stylesheets I can use the same one and resize the same image across all different pages? I mean as in so say the homepage logo is 200px 175px. The next page I wanted to make it 150px 100px is there a way of doing this?

 
Is there a way of doing so? 


Ive tried wrapping divs around them but when I do that and add the image into the div nothing happens when I go to style it

```
  <div class="header-image">
   <img src="images/logo.png" class="rounded mx-auto d-block">
  </div>
```

and code for when I style it

```
   img {
    width: 250px;
    height: 230px;
    margin-top: 60px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could just use a different set of classes in your stylesheet that change the dimensions of the image and apply the ones you want to in the markup on the different pages, for example:

```css
.image--small {
  width: 100px;
}
.image--medium {
  width: 200px;
}
.image--large {
  width: 400px;
}

/*Unimportant rule*/
img {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" class="image--small">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" class="image--medium">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" class="image--large">
```

A great coding methodology to follow when writing css so that is maintainable is known as BEM, [here is a link to check it out](http://getbem.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, it only needs a same kind of declaration on different page. 
It seems like you haven`t referred to the "img" class inside your div. 
Try this:

```css
 .img {
    width: 250px;
    height: 230px;
    margin-top: 60px;
  }
```

```html
 
  <body>
  <div>
   <img src="images/logo.png"  class= "img" >
  </div>
  </body>
```